# Dragon Age: Origins with PlayOnLinux have low fps

Tags: games, performance, playonlinux

I successfully installed Dragon Age: Origins with PlayOnLinux on my Ubuntu 12.04 but the game is too slow, frame per second(fps) is too low. I played this game so many times in Windows with the high graphic settings, so my hardware is enough.

What is the problem, why it's slow, and what can I do to improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "Nvidia Optimus" - Technology ?

Then try this ...

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

& then install this...

http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Hybrid-Grafikkarten/primus

I am playing with primus... It's awesome :)

Comment: The second link you added here is in German while this site is English. Also please don't provide link-only answers.